# How to avoid inf value while feature extracting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, feature-extraction

I’m trying to extract features from some EEG signals. One of the trails in my for loop creates inf value and emd doesn’t accept it so it causes an error! Would you please tell me how I can fix it?!
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
s = 1;
for i = LabelLeft
   SignalL = SignalMean(H.TRIG(i)+fs:H.TRIG(i)+(3*fs)-1,1);
   SignalLeft{s,:} = emd(SignalL,'MAXMODES',4);
   s = s+1;

   clear SignalL
 end
```

Comment: remove it with `isinf` and logical indexing

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you please explain a little more?! Where should I insert this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can inf from array using method shown below:

```
k = [inf 1 2]
k =

   Inf     1     2
k = k(~(isinf(k)))
k =

     1     2
```

Comment: as a shorter alternative `k(isinf(k))=[]`

Comment: I used fillgaps and it seems that the problem has been solved! Thanks